# Xdo not supporting special characters on focused window

Tags: python, ascii, xorg

I am facing a very strange behavior. I use python-libxdo to send text to X windows. When I send text to a window different than the current one, everything works, however if I do the same with the current active one, the not ascii characters are not supported.

Also, in the [PyPi doc](https://pypi.org/project/python-libxdo/) it is specified that a python string must be entered, this is their example, I get an error that way and need to enter a bytes string.

This is for example what I tried.

```
xdo.enter_text_window(ACTIVE_WINDOW, "test@test.com".encode())
```

If doing it to the active window, the "@" will be replaced by a space. If it's not the active window, it will work as expected.

The solution I tried so far was to unfocus the targeted window (W), send the text to the desired not focus now window (W) and focus back to W. That way it works but this bug is very disturbing.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried on another machine with the same archlinux OS and got the exact same behavior. Can someone try this python command on its machine and tell me if s·he gets the same result?

Comment: Still having the same behavior after 3 weeks of updates.

Comment: One month later, still having the same issue. Can someone try it on h·is·er machine please ?